# Adding a delay to a moving object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that moves forward and backwards. Just as it is about to move in the opposite direction, I am trying to add a very brief delay (1.0f) before it moves again.

```
public class PushPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveAmount = 3.3f;
    public float speed = 1.1f;
    private Vector3 startPos;

    void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 v = startPos;
        v.z += moveAmount * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed);
        transform.position = v;
    }

}
```

I attempted to implement a coroutine in two different ways with one of them not working and the other making my entire game basically freeze. I tried to call the method again as well which I am not sure works at all however there were no results.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PushPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveAmount = 3.3f;
    public float speed = 1.1f;
    private Vector3 startPos;

    [SerializeField] private float _delay = 1f;

    void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;

        StartCoroutine(DoMoving());
    }

    private IEnumerator DoMoving()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return DoCycle();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_delay);
        }

        IEnumerator DoCycle()
        {
            var time = 0f;

            while (time * speed < Mathf.PI * 2f)
            {
                Vector3 v = startPos;
                v.z += moveAmount * Mathf.Sin(time * speed);
                transform.position = v;

                yield return null;
                time += Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it would be better to use dotween or dotween + unitask for async moving

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It stops a bit late but I'll try to adjust it.

Comment: `Start` itself can be a coroutine already .. and why that strange nesting of `IEnumerator`? ^^ simply have it in a single nested loop